# Erlang with Erlsom and DTD

Tags: erlang

[image]
I am trying to work with 1 GB XML and DTD file with Erlsom.
The problem is that parse_sax throws an exception becuase it cannot work with DTD file.
Basically i don't need this information so my question is how i tell the
sax_parser to just ignore this?
or even to use try and catch and when the error got catches then to skip this place on the file and continue from there.

This the exception:

```
** exception throw: {error,"Malformed: unknown reference: uuml"}
     in function  erlsom_sax_latin1:nowFinalyTranslate/3 (src/erlsom_sax_latin1.erl, line 1051)
     in call from erlsom_sax_latin1:translateReferenceNonCharacter/4 (src/erlsom_sax_latin1.erl, line 1024)
     in call from erlsom_sax_latin1:parseTextNoIgnore/3 (src/erlsom_sax_latin1.erl, line 922)
     in call from erlsom_sax_latin1:parseContent/2 (src/erlsom_sax_latin1.erl, line 898)
     in call from erlsom_sax_latin1:parse/2 (src/erlsom_sax_latin1.erl, line 172)
     in call from mapReduce:run/0 (/home/alon/workspace/mapReduce/src/mapReduce.erl, line 26)(mapReduce@alon-Vostro-3300)2>
```

The problem is with "uuml" because in the XML file its apear with &uuml

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same error and found this in the [ErlSom](http://orcas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/erlsom/doc/erlsom-0.6.doc) docs under limitations of the sax parser:

> It doesn’t support entities, apart from the predefined ones (< etc.)  and character references (&#nnn; and &#xhhh;).